# Standalone rbac setup for module yii2

Tags: module, yii2, rbac

I`ve got two modules in my yii2-basic application. For common users I have "user" table and for superadmin users I have the second "superadmin" table. There are two users with different sessions in my app - users and superadmins. I need to use different, standalone rbac for superadmin users table. Is it possible to setup two different rbacs in two modules? Now it is setup in web.php file globally. Maybe it is possible somehow to setup authManager in module separately, not in global web.php file?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! In your module.php file specify authManager with different table names, you are supposed to create them before. You also can specify rbac submodule of mdm\admin if you want to use it as well. Specify there another usertable - SuperAdmin in the code below.

```
   public function init()
{
    parent::init();
     $this->modules = [
    'rbac' => [
       'class' => 'mdm\admin\Module',
       'controllerMap' => [
             'assignment' => [
                'class' => 'mdm\admin\controllers\AssignmentController',
                'userClassName' => 'app\models\SuperAdmin', 
                'idField' => 'id',
                'usernameField' => 'username',
            ],
        ],
    'layout' => 'left-menu',
    'mainLayout' => '@app/views/layouts/rbac.php',
    ],
    ];

 $config = [
  'components' => [
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
         'itemTable' => 'superadmin_auth_item',
         'assignmentTable' => 'superadmin_auth_assignment',
         'itemChildTable' => 'superadmin_auth_item_child',
         'ruleTable' => 'superadmin_auth_rule',
    ],
],
    'as access' => [
    'class' => 'app\components\SuperAdminAccessControl',//your overridden AccessControl class
    'allowActions' => [
        'admin/rbac/*',
        'admin/default/login',
        'admin/default/logout',
    ]
   ],
 ];
     \Yii::$app->authManager->itemTable = 'superadmin_auth_item';
     \Yii::$app->authManager->assignmentTable = 'superadmin_auth_assignment';
     \Yii::$app->authManager->itemChildTable = 'superadmin_auth_item_child';
     \Yii::$app->authManager->ruleTable = 'superadmin_auth_rule';

     \Yii::configure(\Yii::$app, $config);

  }
```

Overridden AccessControl class:

```
namespace app\components;
class SuperAdminAccessControl extends \mdm\admin\components\AccessControl
{
   function __construct() {
       $this->setUser('superadmin');//table name
  }
}
```